# Wanting same banner/nav menu on each page in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails. I currently have 3 pages in my web app. I am wondering what is the "cool rails way" where I can easily implement the same banner (pic/website logo/text) and horizontal navigation menu on each page with out having to copy and paste the code or create separate CSS files for each page. Is this possible? Would like to stick with Ruby/Rails/CSS/HTML.

Also, It seems that if I create a css element titled banner for one view of one controller another view of a different controller has the same styling. Is there something going on behind the scenes here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually accomplished through application.html.erb.  You put the header of your web site in that page followed by a <%= yield %> statement and then the footer.  The yield statement inserts the content from whatever action is being processed.

For example:

application.html.erb

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My cool web site header and menu!</h1>
<%=yield %>
<p>Web site footer</p>
```

index.html.erb

```
<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
<% @stuff.each do |thing| %>
   <li><%=thing.name%></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

The contents of index.html.erb will be inserted into the application.html.erb at the spot where <%=yield %> appears.

Answer (score 0):

Following this tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book ,
the way to do it is to use `render`method.

example code from the tutorial:
`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" =>
  true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" =>
  true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
<body>
  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render 'layouts/flash' %>
    <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

According to the tutorial, the way in rails to pack up a logical unit in one place is to use a facility called partials.

For example, you can pack up your navigation bar in `app/views/layouts/_navbar.html.erb`
then it can be rendered in the layout with `<%= render 'layouts/navbar' %>`

More about the parials: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-partials

Rails defaults to concatenating all CSS files into one master. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html